# Animating the hole in a boolean object

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, boolean-modifier

[image]I want to create a boolean object where the object being subtracted is an extruded curve I can animate.

As I currently understand booleans, my curve needs to first be converted to a mesh, which can then be extruded and that object can be used in a boolean. But converting to a mesh means I can no longer animate the shape of the curve. How can I create a boolean where I can animate the curvature of the object being subtracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add this geometry nodes modifier to your curve:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Yes, the geometry nodes setup converts your curve to a mesh and uses then mesh boolean to do the boolean cut. But it is still a curve (as long as you do not apply the GN modifier) and you still can modify the curve as you want.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. Could you share this project? I tried recreating your set up and no hole appears

Comment: i added it. Make sure your plane and your curve are on the same flat level. Then it should work. If you move the vertices, you should move them with G Shift-Z so you won't get unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: It looks like I misinterpreted your question as before your edit I thought that you were talking about a 3D curve...

You can still use a curve: Create a cylinder (with no cap), give it an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier, use it as a *Boolean* object, in the *Boolean* modifier it looks like you need to enable the *Hole Tolerant* option:

[image]

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thanks for the response. I added a picture to my original post. I'd like to have a closed curve act as the shape of the hole in my boolean, not as the path like in your screenshot. I want to animate the points on the curve that I have and have the hole follow.

Comment: @moonboots: i still don't understand that the moderators don't ban u for years because of your sexual pictures.... :D +1 ....sexy!!!

Comment: yes don't tell them that i'm addict to cube p0rn

Comment: my lips are sealed....!!!!